# What are matplotlib's spine_types?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The matplotlib documentation for [spines](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html) shows that a `str` parameter `spine_type` is required to construct a Spine instance.  The documentation doesn't indicate what spine_types are possible or provide a link.  I've used the documenation search feature, web search, and Stack Overflow search, and I can't find a hint of these.

What are the matplotlib spine_types?  Links to documentation are especially appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/spines.html#Spine), it's : "left", "right", "top", "bottom".

Comment: There is also "circle".

Comment: No, circle is not a spine_type.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How do you explain `if self.spine_type == 'circle':` (found twice) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link!  From skimming the source code, it seems to be as simple as this.